# Ruby-on-Rails Whenever by Javan working step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, cron-task

I follow the railscast whenever by javan tutorial but I seems to unable to make it happen.
Is there a MUST to install capistrano to have cron job? it is because I don't have the deploy.rb. I list down the steps in details. If there any steps I had missed to cause my cron not working? I always get a report say I got a new mail but I didnt send any email operation.

Step1:

```
wheneverize .
```

====>   schedule.rb in config folder

Step 2:
[Scheduler.rb]

```
every '1 * * * *' do
   runner 'Company.count'
end
```

Step 3: [what is "store"?]

```
whenever --update-crontab store
```

Step 4: [config/deploy.rb]<-- I don't have deploy files so I create it myself.

```
after "deploy:symlink", "deploy:update_crontab"  

namespace :deploy do  
  desc "Update the crontab file"  
  task :update_crontab, :roles => :db do  
     run "cd #{release_path} && whenever --update-crontab #{application}"  
  end  
end
```

Step 5 :

```
whenever --update-crontab store

crontab -l
```

What have I missed? why it didnt work? Please enlighten me step by step because I am newbie in ROR.. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [Whenever docs](https://github.com/javan/whenever) have an example of deploying *Whenever* with *Capistrano*. Just add the following to the top of your *Capistrano* deploy config.

```
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"  # set this first if using bundler
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

Then *Whenever* will install into *cron* as part of the deploy.

---

**UPDATE**

To test that *Whenever* was successfully updated *cron*, *ssh* to the target machine as the Capistrano deploy user for the target machine and run `crontab -l`. You should see output similar to this:

```
crontab -l

# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: app_name
0 0 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /opt/path/app_name/releases/20120321133343 && RAILS_ENV=production rake group:task --silent'

0 3 * * 6 /bin/bash -l -c '/opt/path/app_name/shared/bin/script'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: app_name
```

Comment: in deploy.rb file? and bundle install it will do?

Comment: Yeah, the in deploy.rb. When you deploy, Whenever will use bundle to update cron at the deploy target